# Dynamically updating background color when user signs in but when he sign out,the background color does not changes but only on reload

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, material-ui, redux-observable

This is the code snippet for what I am trying to do. currentUser is updated when the user signs in or logs out.

```
interface StyleAppBar {
    backgroundColor: string;
    boxShadow: string;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, StyleAppBar>((theme) =>
    createStyles({
        appBar: {
            background: (muiProps) => muiProps.backgroundColor,
            boxShadow: (muiProps) => muiProps.boxShadow,
        },
    })
);

const Navbar: FC<NavbarProps> = (props) => {
    const { currentUser, signOut } = props;


    const muiProps = {
        backgroundColor: currentUser ? 'white' : 'primary',
        boxShadow: currentUser ? 'none' : 'primary',
    };

    const classes = useStyles(muiProps);

    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar position="static" className={classes.appBar}>
```

The other implementation I tried worked as when the user signed out, the color is changing back as specified in the code. In the implementation, I defined useStyles inside Navbar component not outside as seen in above component. Though I feel this might not be the correct approach. Please let me know if there is other efficient work around.
I am using Material-UI, React , Redux-Observable , Firebase.
Thank you

Comment: This code is not enough to help you, try to provide a working sandbox.

Comment: Sure, then i'll try to provide a sandbox but my question is, can I put 

`const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, StyleAppBar>((theme) => ....`
   
Inside Navbar component. Will that a create a problem ?

Comment: Apparently this will create a problem. For me, from the first pass, this did not affect all the components.

Comment: In your implementation you are also missing out: <div className={`${classes.foo} ${classes.bar}`} />
Adapting based on props: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this option will solve your problem:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  appBar1: {
    background: 'white',
    boxShadow: 'none',
  },
  appBar2: {
    background: 'primary',
    boxShadow: 'primary',
    },    
}));
    
const Navbar: FC<NavbarProps> = (props) => {
    const { currentUser, signOut } = props;
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar position="static" className={currentUser ? classes.appBar1 : classes.appBar2}>   
    ...
```